# Can't uninstall SDKMAN on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, uninstallation, macos-catalina, sdkman

So I want to uninstall SDKMAN on my macOS, I was following this step for SDKMAN uninstallation instruction, `rm -rf ~/.sdkman`, but it's doesn't work for my mac

```
rm -rf ~/.sdkman
```

and when I type `SDK version` on my macOS console my uninstallation step is not working, this is the result when I type `SDK version`.

[image: invalid command]

I use macOS operating system, version `Catalina`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? The same thing happened to me.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.sdkman` worked for me

Comment: it is sourced into your shell - just log in again and it will be gone. You might also remove it's source-in lines at the end of your ~/.bashrc (3 lines /w comment) although it is save to leave em in there as well.

Answer (score 8):

[The last step](https://sdkman.io/install#:%7E:text=uninstallation) involves editing and removing the initialization snippet from your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and/or `.profile` files. If you use ZSH, remove it from the `.zshrc` file. The snippet of code to be removed looks something like this:

If in you system exists `.zshrc`

Edit `.zshrc`

```
~ nano .zshrc
```

And delete this text:

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
[[ -s "/home/dudette/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/dudette/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Once removed, you have successfully uninstalled SDKMAN! from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

try to type in terminal macos

> sudo mv ~/.sdkman

or is not work

> sudo mv /Users/yourname/sdkman/

i hope this work